# phpMyAdmin won't display Unicode (utf-8) characters properly into database but show correctly in the web

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

sorry if my question is duplicate , after googling i found a answer for my question that says:

```
 1-go to libraries folder
 2-finding file database_interface.lib.php
 3-comment below code:


  if (! empty($GLOBALS['collation_connection'])) {
  PMA_DBI_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';", $link, PMA_DBI_QUERY_STORE);
   $mysql_charset = explode('_', $GLOBALS['collation_connection']);
   PMA_DBI_query("SET collation_connection = '" .      PMA_sqlAddslashes($GLOBALS['collation_connection']) . "';", $link,

  PMA_DBI_QUERY_STORE);
   } else {
   PMA_DBI_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';", $link,      PMA_DBI_QUERY_STORE);
 }
```

now my problem is i do not have (database_interface.lib.php) in libraries folder

version of my xampp is 3.2.2

Comment: phpmyadmin probably has correct configuration, and your website has some problematic collate/charset. I will be much safer for you to fix the problem in your database (and not change the way phpmyadmin works).

Comment: i have added (<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />) in head tag of html page , any way how i can solve the problem. i use mysqli for connecting.

Comment: You probably have default connection charset/collate. You should change them.

Comment: i have used (utf8_unicode_ci) for collation of database in phpmyadmin. if i have to change some where else please explain more.

Comment: It's the database configuration, it's the server configuration.

Comment: you mean what i have done is database configuration, and now i have to change some thing in server configuration, please how?

Comment: According answer to this question i do not have file mysqli.dbi.lib.php in my xampp

Comment: That code seems unnecessarily complex; simply issue the `SET NAMES...`.

Comment: Since you have not said which of about 5 erroneous outputs you are getting, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added below code before any insert and select statements, and now it works.

$conn->set_charset('utf8');